# Task 'generateDebugSources' not found in project ':app'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I been developing my app in my Macbook and I put my project in Github.

I got a windows laptop and cloned my project from Github but when I build my app I'm getting these errors and my app won't build:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'generateDebugSources' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you must include your `build.gradle` file into your question to detect error reason

Answer (score 1):

Please Check for file "YourProject/app/build.gradle" may be it is not there or it get corrupted( some times due to power failure the current running file become blank ). if you have older backup copy all syntax from there and past it on   "YourProject/app/build.gradle".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in Android Studio by running `File > Invalidate Caches...`